# Is conversion of int to double of a column valid in presto?

Tags: sql, database, hive, presto

I am trying to change the data type of a column from **int** to **double** by using the alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE schema_name.table_name CHANGE COLUMN col1 col1 double CASCADE;
```

Now, if I run a select query over the table on presto:

```
select * from schema_name.table_name where partition_column = '2022-12-01
```

I get the error:

> schema_name.table_name is declared as type double, but the Parquet
> file
> (hdfs://ns-platinum-prod-phx/secure/user/hive/warehouse/db_name.db/table_name/partition_column=2022-12-01/000002_0)
> declares the column as type INT32"

However, if I run the query on Hive, it provides me the output.

I tried digging into the this, by creating a copy table of the source and deleting the partiton from hdfs. However, I run into the same problem again. Is there any other way to resolve this as this table contains huge data.

Comment: Can you try to set hive.parquet.use-column-names  to true

Comment: I think ```hive.parquet.use-column-names = true``` lets me access with column names in presto rather than their ordinal positions defined. I guess it doesn't have anything to do with datatypes. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the data type of the Hive table as the parquet files created in HDFS for older partitions won’t get updated.
The only fix is to create a new table and load the data into the new table from the older table.